# Code works in jsfiddle but not in my application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I want to know if comebody can do me a big favour, in my jsfiddle it shows the whole code in my application. Now if you click on the link (Open Grid) and select a button, it would displays the right number of buttons below. E.G if user selects button "1", it would display button "A", if somebody selects button "2", then it would display buttons "A" and "B" and so on and so on. My problem is that it works in jsfiddle but it does not work in my app, (I am using Crimson Editor). I am wondering if somebody can copy this code in their text editor or web programming software and see if it work on their page because in my application it does not display the buttons below after selecting a button from the grid. Can you let me know if it works or not, thank you.

my code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aphk/)

Comment: Can you post console error messages?

Comment: I am only getting one which is: "Error: Image corrupt or truncated: <unknown>
Source File: <unknown>
Line: 0." There are no other error messages. There is 3 warnings that resize:none; is not a css property but I need this so textarea cannot be resized

Comment: Please try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aphk/) In your posted jsfiddle you have added javascript in body part but it should be in head. So I have changed it and added jquery's ready function (DOM ready event)

Comment: Hi sorry I can't see difference in code, can you point out where you put code in jsfiddle plz

Comment: I have added whole javascript inside $(document).ready (function () {}); After whole DOM is initialized. Before that you can not access any element using $ notation as it may not be loaded at all.

Comment: I still see no difference, are you sure you are updating the jsfiddle or just running it?

Comment: Why do you have HTML in the Javascript box?

Comment: It is ok I managed to get it working by including the $(document).ready ... function and putting the javascript in that function. If you can put your comment as an answer then I will mark it as best answer if you want.

Comment: @MalcolmPickup Sorry I didn't know, that for sharing you need to save the code manually in jsfiddle. I have posted that comment as answer and also updated link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to access any DOM element, you should do it after domready event. As it might be possible while script execution that element doesn't exist.

So any DOm related function such as `$("elementid")` should be used only after domready event. For doing this Jquery provide `$.ready()` function.

So, if you put all your code inside `$.ready()`, it will work correctly.

It was working in Jsfiddle, because you have selected to place JavaScript in body tag (notice no wrap body). So it will get executed when webpage is loaded.

[Link to corrected code](http://jsfiddle.net/9Aphk/1/)